# How can Windows file explorer delete a folder that RMDIR can delete?

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing

Windows Server 2012 (not R2) shows folders in use with read in open files in computer management.  Windows explorer does not allow us to delete those folders no matter what we try, however rmdir as the same user can delete them without issue.

We are logged in as Administrator, we have ownership of the files, have all permissions for that user, etc.  We even close the open folders that show in Open Files in computer management prior to trying, but it always fails with *needs Administrator privileges* repeatedly no matter how fast we click.

If we run a command prompt and perform a

`rmdir /s /q foldername`

It always successfully deletes the folder under the same conditions.

How can we get users over the network to delete these folders instead of an Administrative server command prompt?  (I am also interested in why rmdir works and other attempts do not.)

Comment: You're using an elevated command prompt, right?  That's why it works.  Best approach is to make sure that the permissions give access to some group (other than Administrators, Domain Admins, or any other special group) and use an account belonging to that group.

Comment: @harryjohnston The permissions on the folder I created logged in as Administrator that I can change show the same as the one I cannot change, including owner. The only difference I can see is domain users showing open read access under open files. If I restart the domain users machine, I can change the folder as Administrator. Closing their open folders under open files does not have any effect, still showing after a refresh. If I delete the folder, it does not delete until they restart their machine, then it instantly deletes like it is pending.

Comment: Sounds like there's a file or folder pending deletion, the file system won't let you do anything to a file or folder in that state.  But if rmdir works that can't be the case.  Using rmdir also shouldn't work if a folder is in use.  What happens if, rather than restarting the end user's machine, you use Computer Management to disconnect their session?

Comment: ... are the end users using the Windows command line?  That's usually how I wind up with folders left open unintentionally.  The first step to resolving this (as an end user) is to check that the folder I want to remove isn't the current directory for any of the open command line windows, and if that doesn't work, I have to close any applications (e.g., notepad) that I might have launched from a command line window.